# How to share the app result in Facebook? what is the permission required?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a facebook application. I want to share the application result to user wall. What is the permission required. I have tried for publish_action, its not approved since user defined their own message. What is the alternative way to publish or share the app result in facebook.

My app:http://makepenny.com/ProfilePictureCounter/index.html

Comment: Either let your users share a link, where you put the information into the title and description of that link; or look into Open Graph stories.

Comment: Hi the link returns old metadata, i pass dynamic data. Can u give some more clue about Open Graph stories.

Comment: Clue: Open Graph stories are explained in great detail in the documentation.